# Failure to load properly Groovy library into Groovy shell executing script

Tags: java, groovy, groovyshell

My software used groovy.lang Java package to execute Groovy scripts from a shell, binding the variables in the script to Java objects.

A typical script looks like:

```
package packagename

// import Java classes


abstract class MyClass extends Script {
    def myfunction() {
    }
}
```

in this example, 'myfunction' will be called from the outside.

The scripts (located at the file system) are loaded by the following sequence from Java -
the code returns GroovyShell class instance:

```
GroovyClassLoader groovyClassLoader = new GroovyClassLoader(...)
File groovyFile = new File(groovyURL.toURI());
Class<?> groovyClass = groovyClassLoader.parseClass(groovyFile);
CompilerConfiguration groovyConfig = new CompilerConfiguration();
groovyConfig.setScriptBaseClass(groovyClass.getName());
return new GroovyShell(groovyClassLoader, new Binding(), groovyConfig);
```

**My design goal is to add a Groovy library that can be shared between scripts**
My preference is to implement a class (adding lines into the existing script seems to be a hack).

I made a simple class representing the library code. Right now, it looks like:

```
package shared

class MySharedLib
{
    static def testFunction()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

To make sure the class it loaded, I added a call to

```
groovyClassLoader.parseClass(groovyLibraryFile)
```

before loading the actual script by:

groovyClassLoader.parseClass(groovyFile);

Now, from the script, I can call the library:

```
shared.MySharedLib.testFunction()
```

indeed return the string "test".

However, when trying to do the import via:

```
import shared.MySharedLib
```

in the script (before class definition) - I always got an error when loading the script:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
script754084858.groovy: 14: unable to resolve class shared.MySharedLib
 @ line 14, column 1.
```

Tried to modify the classpath, it did not help. I realize something is wrong with my setup.
Will appreciate any tip how to load a Groovy library in the correct way.

Max

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your approach. I tried out the way you described and it works as expected. Can you please provide the script in which it fails?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comments.
I think I understand the cause.
It turns out that at some point, the "script" is being compiled using

```
GroovyClassLoader classLoader = new GroovyClassLoader(parentClassLoader);
GroovyCodeSource codeSource = new GroovyCodeSource(code, scriptClassName + ".groovy", "/groovy/script");
CompilationUnit cu = new CompilationUnit(classLoader);
cu.addSource(codeSource.getName(), codeSource.getScriptText());
cu.compile(CompilePhase.CLASS_GENERATION.getPhaseNumber());
```

The compilation fails when reaching the "import" statement, since the library class is not in the classpath, so it's unreachable.

Calling **classLoader.addClasspath(path)** with the appropriate path solves the issue.
So the problem was related to compilation - not to execution.